# Moai SDK isn't downloadable

Tags: broken-links, moai

I can't download Moai SDK from http://getmoai.com/sdk/moai-sdk-download.html -
I always get the message

> ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved

I don't know if is it because of my area or something else, but I'd really really appreciate anyone who'd give me another mirror or share Moai SDK in some cloud s.a *4shared* or *www.dropbox.com*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download Moai from [the Moai Github repository](https://github.com/moai/moai-dev), the version can be chosen with the branch button (choose Tags - Version-1.4p0 for the latest release version)

[image: branch]

...then click `Download ZIP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last stable(Version 1.4p0) release here : https://mega.co.nz/#!SE8x0CxK!Bu-KnVh3St7TtsuHKSJbCi-AI3ELEShwyfIcm3-BFKM

Please note that above zip does not contain source.